# class mutating data of other class

Tags: c++, class, oop

I have two classes called Data and A. class A is mainly a collection of functions that manipulate data in Data. Now I need a way for A to access all the data in Data. I know two ways of doing so.

1. I can pass a reference of Data to A but then I always have to write the prefix "Data." which I think is really annoying and there is no ambiguity anyway.
2. I can make A a superclass of Data. But some methods in A call another class B which also mutates the class Data and in this approach I am not sure how this can be done.

So my question is: Is there another way for A to access the data in Data that would be more suitable?

Comment: From what you describe it seems you split the class in two: one holds the data, the other contains the code that operates on the data. In OOP, the data and the code that handles it belong to the same class.

Comment: But a couple of classes operate on the data and putting everything in one huge class seems wrong to me.

Comment: If the class is huge then can you say it really observes the [single responsibility principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)? Perhaps the key is to break down the functionality into several classes, rather than ship out the functions to a different class. Check out [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)) and watch some [uncle bob vids](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=uncle+bob+martin) on youtube.

Comment: Maybe there is content (data and code) for several classes that need to collaborate and you cannot see them yet (and think all the code belongs to a single class). Play with them, write tests, refactor them; at some point (not today but after days or even weeks of working with them) the need for separation (and the boundaries) will become very clear. As @PaulRooney also suggests in the comment above, a large number of methods usually means more than one responsibility crammed in a single class. It's impossible to provide a more specific advice without seeing the code, though.

Comment: Prefixing "Data" way, is a good way to do it, and in development you can not escape from that, and that should be the least thing to annoy you :), and have some Getter methods in Data. This is a better design than using friend.

Answer (score 1):

The concept you're looking for is called a [friend](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/friend) class. Friend classes have access to the private members of the class they are declared in. So, you'd have something like

```
class A; //Forward declaration
class Data
{
friend class A; //Forward friend declaration, instances of A
                //can access private members of Data
public:
    //Implementation details
private:
    int m_myData;
};

class A
{
    //Do whatever to an  instance of Data (probably take it by reference)
public:
    void multiplyData(Data &data, int multiple) { data.m_myData *= multiple; }
};
```

Comment: just pointing out access specifiers have no effect on the meaning of friend declarations; the way you put it indented under "private:" might cause confusion that it is somehow a private declaration. This is purely aesthetics, but, still.

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou Yeah, good point. Thanks for mentioning it. It was indeed for aesthetics, but I'll edit it to move it after the initial class declaration. Thanks again.

Answer (score -1):

If the question is about to access Data from Class A, then declare the Data as global. You can very well access by anyone. It can be Class A also. Use the class data as header file to class A implementation, all the public member of Data will available to class A.

Comment: This is just about the worst possible thing you could do.   Please read this thread: http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/148108/why-is-global-state-so-evil

Comment: Yes you are correct, global data are evil. Thank you

Comment: It can be this way use the Class data as header file & access all members of that.